# How to show SuperScript,SubScript in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7

how can we achieve superscript and subscript effect like subscript,superscript, smallcaps etc in Windows Phone 7.1?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight does not support the `BaseLineAlignment` property from WPF, which enables you to use subscript & superscript text...

The alternative is to use the chars already available in the Unicode table!

Please check [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/64169.aspx/1) and [here](http://varshavmane.blogspot.in/2010/04/how-to-wirte-maths-equation-in.html) for more information and a possible solution to your problem!